# Converting string to moment gives wrong year

Tags: momentjs

This is my code in js:

```
var x = "2017-1-2";
var y = moment(x, "yyyy-MM-DD")
```

And when I watch y in console this is what it is:

[image]

As you can see, the _d has the correct day and monthe, but the wrong year. Why is this happening and how to fix it? I use that value to send it to server via ajax and the wrong year gets sent.

Comment: I have never played with Moment.js before, but assuming ``moment`` is a constructor, would you not use the ``new`` keyword?

Comment: @JoshCrowe No, to create a new moment object you don't need the new keyword :)

Comment: Ah, it's a function with a return, not a constructor. Gotcha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use uppercase `YYYY` instead. It is mentioned in the [docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/). Also don't forget that construction using `moment()` will treat the date as local date and then convert it into UTC. If you want to treat the date as UTC, you can use `moment.utc()`.

In my timezone (GMT+7) the code below will show `"2017-01-01T17:00:00.000Z"`.

```js
var x = "2017-1-2";
var y = moment(x, "YYYY-MM-DD")
console.log(y);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.16.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```